# Create instances of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a map with a bunch of buttons that show and hide container div's. I don't want to assign the same code to each button because it's all the same.

I was thinking to create a variable when the button is clicked so it could replace a part in the DIV ID (handler?)

So I could refer to `#fiche_8_1980_img_container` as `#fiche_VARIABLE`.

Second part of my question is the animation functions I do are all looking like this:

```
  $('#fiche_8_1980_img_container').animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {});
```

Is there a way to put this in an instance or object so I could call it easier?

Here is a piece of code that I use for the button.

```
$('#button_8_algiers').click(function() {
        $('#fiche_8_1980_img_container').css('visibility','visible');
                $('#fiche_8_1980_img_container').animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {
                });     
        });
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great, I don't know where to start looking...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would something like this help?

```
var ficheHandler = {
   animateFiche: function(fiche) {
      fiche
         .css('visibility','visible');
         .animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {
          });
   }
}


$('#button_8_algiers').click(function() {
     ficheHandler.animateFiche($('#fiche_8_1980_img_container'));
});
```

Comment: That seems exactly what I need, I didn't know what the syntax was to put functions into variables. Do you have any idea how to call variables in div handlers (#button_VARIABLE)? Many thanks!

Comment: *call variables* ? What you're trying to achieve is (tell me if i'm wrong): Havin the variables as part of DIV-HTML + calling the same func for any div, applying these vars?

Comment: I'd like to user one script that could be altered using variables to show/hide a bunch of layers with the animation. So I was thinking of adding a mouseover event to the button which would create a variable ie. "8_algiers" that I could use to alter the function handler. So "$('#button_8_algiers')" would become $('#button_VARIABLE').

So I could just use one script for all the buttons that share the same how/hide functions. I hope you can make sense of all this? Thx anyways!

Comment: I'm also getting an error in the script you wrote             ".animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {" but I don't see it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this which is basically using the help of `jQuery` chaining so there is no need to cache the object into local variables.

```
$('#button_8_algiers').click(function() {
        $('#fiche_8_1980_img_container').css('visibility','visible');
        .animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {
        });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have control over the HTML. If you have that many buttons with shared functionality, give them the same CSS class, and add a unique identifier in either the rel or data attributes:

```
$('a.myButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target')).fadeIn(150);
});
```